# whether the VSCode terminal can be automatically adapted？

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Problem description:**
First, I zoom out the Terminal window;
Then, I run a command;
Finally, wait until the command is complete, as shown in the following figure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APhGy.png)

**Doubts**
After the running is complete, I maximize the VSCode. However, the information in Terminal does not change as the VSCode is maximized. It is still the width of the previous window.

Is there a way to enable the output information to change with the VSCode maximization?

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di0I2.png)

The red box is the running result of my VSCode windowing.
The blue box is the result of my VSCode maximization.
What I want to achieve is that when I maximize VSCode, the windowed log can be the same as below, changing with the size of the screen.

Comment: Add which terminal it uses. `cmd` or `PowerShell`, or another.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I understand your problem; you are wanting to increase the size of the terminal window that opens in vsc, correct?

You can start by contracting the explorer that you have on the left side of your screen; I attached a photo

[Collapsed Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6GDW.png)

On the other hand, if you want to increase the size of the terminal tab, what you can do is drag to the top that you like the most, I attached a photo

[enlarged terminal size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTjLU.png)

Comment: thanks for your answer.I updated the picture to better describe the problem.

Comment: > with pleasure